# Want to hide page name in url

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I just need to know how can I stop displaying my php pages name in url
for example:

> http://cbse.in/classxii/question_papers.php to http://cbse.in/classxii/ or http://cbse.in/classxii/question_papers/
>
> http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/question_papers.php to http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/ or http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/question_papers/
>
> http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/Chapter1/answers.php to http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/Chapter1/ or http://cbse.in/classxii/computer_science/Chapter1/answers/

I came to know this is possible by URL rewriting in htaccess.

But not clear idea on this, it will great if someone show me the correct and clear way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this link for info about htaccess redirection. Also, pls make sure that you've got it enabled within Apache, the webserver.

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @neeaglThank you I tested on 1 page and successful. Its a request if you can tell me does this url rewriting give any kind of bad effect for google search

Comment: No it doesn't. In fact the URL rewrite helps the search engine picking up the most relevant keywords to your page since the rewrite URL would be more user-friendly.

Comment: Your welcome. If you are happy with the answer, please upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Mod Rewrite. You can use this one Mod Rewrite generator: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: Your link is helpful Thank you